# Existence property for second-order propositional logic

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, type-theory

Consider the intuitionistic second-order propositional calculus (SOL) formulated in the full $\wedge,\vee,\rightarrow,\bot,\top,\forall,\exists$ language.

**Question:** Assume that $\Gamma$ and $\Psi$ are quantifier-free. Assume further that $\Gamma \vdash \exists X. \Psi(X)$ is derivable in intuitionistic propositional SOL. Can we find a *quantifier-free* formula $T$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \Psi(T)$ is derivable?

The question is motivated by trying to get a better understanding of the predicative variant of SOL studied e.g. by [F. Ferreira](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10992-005-9001-z)), which restricts substitution in the $\exists R$ and $\forall L$ rules to quantifier-free formula.

Comment: *edit note*: I changed the title of this question, and edited the order of the presentation, so that the actual question being asked can be ascertained faster.

Comment: Do you not need to specify a proof system for SOL? Is there a canonical choice?

Comment: @James Hanson: Indeed. Iintuitionistic propositional SOL _is_ defined by a proof system, it's giving it _semantics_ that's hard. The canonical rules are the sequent rules $\Gamma \vdash P[X:=T]  $\Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash \exists X. P$ and $\Gamma, P[X:=Y] \vdash \Delta  $\Rightarrow \Gamma, \exists X.P \vdash \Delta$ (where $X$ is a variable, $Y$ is a fresh variable, and $T$ is an _arbitrary_ formula) for the existential quantifier, and dual rules for the universal $\forall$, added to the usual sequent calculus for intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Is this written somewhere?

Comment: @JamesHanson: In many places, first in [Takeuti's 1953 article](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjm1924/23/0/23_0_39/_pdf/-char/en). But that presentation is a bit long-winded: you can see the rules at a glance in e.g. Fig. 1 of [Hermant-Lipton](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-87531-4_14), and in many other articles. Basically, this is the system that was the subject of [Takeuti's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takeuti%27s_conjecture), settled by Tait-Girard-others in the late 60s/early 70s.

Comment: Isn't this going to fail in the following way: Let $\varphi(x)$ be some complicated formula with high quantifier complexity. We then have that $\vdash \forall x (\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$, so $\vdash \exists Y \forall x (\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow Y(x))$. Assuming you chose $\varphi(x)$ correctly, there isn't going to be a quantifier-free formula equivalent to it.

Comment: @JamesHanson: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand this strategy. I assume that $\Gamma, \Psi$ are both quantifier-free. Vut if I regard $\exists Y.\forall x. \varphi(x) \rightarrow Y(x))$ as having the form $\exists Y. \Psi(Y)$ then $\Psi$ is not quantifier-free. Am I blanking on some simple further idea that'd make it work?

Comment: Ah right sorry, I missed the stipulation that $\Psi$ is quantifier-free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question, strictly speaking, is **negative**. For instance take the sequent $P \vee Q \vdash \exists X ((X \wedge P) \vee (\neg X \wedge Q))$, which is (intuitionistically) derivable since both the following are:

- $P \vdash \exists X ((X \wedge P) \vee (\neg X \wedge Q))$ by setting $X = \top$; and,
- $Q \vdash \exists X ((X \wedge P) \vee (\neg X \wedge Q))$ by setting $X = \bot$.

However note that no single formula $\chi$ can witness the existential when the antecedent is $P\vee Q$, regardless of whether it is quantifier-free or not. To see this suppose for contradiction that $P\vee Q \vdash (\chi \wedge P) \vee (\neg \chi \wedge Q)$ is derivable. This implies the derivability of both:

- $P \vdash (\chi \wedge P) \vee (\neg \chi \wedge Q)$; and,
- $Q \vdash (\chi \wedge P) \vee (\neg \chi \wedge Q)$.

By the disjunction property (or simply the only possible rule application in bottom-up cut-free proof search), and since we have neither $P\vdash Q$ nor $Q\vdash P$, we must have derivability of both:

- $P \vdash \chi$; and,
- $Q \vdash \neg \chi$.

However this is not even classsically possible, as one of $\chi$ and $\neg \chi$ is always false, and so contradicts the assignment that sets both $P$ and $Q$ true.

Usually for disjunction and existential properties to hold in the presence of a context $\Gamma$ one requires some further conditions, e.g. that $\Gamma$ consists only of [Harrop formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrop_formula) (this is sufficient but not necessary).

Of course we could reformulate the question to assume that $\Gamma$ is Harrop (or similar), but more generally let us just suppose that $\Gamma \vdash \exists X \psi(X)$ is derivable and has a *second-order witness*, say $\chi$, i.e. that $\Gamma \vdash \psi(\chi)$ is derivable and address whether there is necessarily a *quantifier-free* such witness. The answer to this question is indeed **positive** by the following argument.

It is well known that first-order intuitionistic propositional logic enjoys *uniform interpolation*, and so interprets its second-order version, a result due to [Pitts](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275175). In fact there is such an interpretation that commutes with all of first-order intuitionistic propositional logic, say the $*$-translation in Section 3 of [Pitts](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275175). So we can reason as follows:

- Assume $\Gamma \vdash \psi(\chi)$ is derivable.
- Then also $\Gamma^* \vdash (\psi(\chi))^*$ is derivable by Proposition 9 of [Pitts](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2275175).
- Since $*$ commutes with (first-order) propositional connectives we have that $\Gamma^* = \Gamma$ and $(\psi(\chi))^* = \psi(\chi^*)$ and so $\Gamma \vdash \psi(\chi^*)$ is derivable.
- However $\chi^*$ is quantifier-free, and so serves as the desired witness.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Funnily enough, the Pitts quantifier theorem was the main workhorse of the article I was writing that led me to ask the question in the first place, but somehow I still failed to observe its implications for the Harrop case .

Comment: No problem! I hope the second part of my answer is nonetheless useful.